# Are all $AR(p)$ processes for which $|a_1|,....,|a_p| < 1$ stationary?

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity, autoregressive

For an $AR(p)$ process $ Y_t = a_1Y_{t-1}+a_2Y_{t-2}+...+a_qY_{t-q}$ :

Is having the coefficients $|a_1|,....,|a_p| < 1$ just a necessary condition for stationarity, or is it sufficient as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly not sufficient, try the AR(2) process
$$
Y_t = 0.5Y_{t-1}+0.5Y_{t-2}+u_t
$$
for which not all roots of the equation $1-0.5z-0.5z^2$ are outside the unit circle:

```
> polyroot(c(1, -0.5, -0.5))
[1]  1-0i -2+0i
```

Your condition is, moreover, also not necessary: try
$$
Y_t = 1.1Y_{t-1}-0.9Y_{t-2}+u_t,
$$
whose characteristic polynomial has all roots outside the unit circle:

```
> Re(polyroot(c(1, -1.1, 0.9)))^2+Im(polyroot(c(1, -1.1, 0.9)))^2
[1] 1.111111 1.111111
```

Here are the real and imaginary parts together with the unit circle:

[image]

```
library(plotrix)
plot(Re(polyroot(c(1, -1.1, 0.9))),Im(polyroot(c(1, -1.1, 0.9))),asp=1,ylim=c(-1,1),xlim=c(-1,1),col="red",pch=19)
draw.circle(0, 0, 1)
```

A necessary condition that I would argue is useful is given by
$$\sum_{j=1}^pa_j<1,$$ see e.g. [here, p. 54](http://www.springer.com/de/book/9783540735670).

Comment: Are you saying $Y_t = 1.1Y_{t-1}-0.9Y_{t-2}+u_t$ is stationary?

Comment: Yes, because all roots are outside the unit circle. Try 
`plot(arima.sim(list(ar=c(1.1,-0.9)),n=1000))`.

Comment: @Alex, effectively, the large negative coefficient on the second lag "undoes" the large positive on the first lag, so that, overall, the process does not become explosive.

Comment: @ChristophHanck The necessary condition you are citing at the bottom of your reply is exactly a condition I have been trying to establish here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4441327/explanation-reference-request-for-necessary-and-sufficent-conditions-for-polynom . Any chance you could point me to a reference that proves this result, alternatively hint at how I could proceed? I tried to check out the reference in the link you provided, but I could not locate the result (and I do not speak german). Thanks a lot if you have anything to add!